# Map Annotations from JSON -- No annotations showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I need to read from a JSON file atURL and make an annotation for each "name,lat,lon." Here's the code I've got so far, which compiles but does not display anything. And ideas?

IOS6, Storyboards

_ Added Code _

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *downloadData;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _downloadData = [NSMutableData new];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"OMITTED/apptest/locations.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_downloadData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    id parsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *pointInfo in parsed)
    {
        NSLog([parsed objectForKey:@"name"]);
        double xCoord = [(NSNumber*)[parsed objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        double yCoord = [(NSNumber*)[parsed objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(xCoord, yCoord);


        MKPointAnnotation *point = [MKPointAnnotation new];
        point.coordinate = coords;
        point.title = [parsed objectForKey:@"name"];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point]; // or whatever your map view's variable name is
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // ARC Problem --- [_mapView release];
    self.mapView = nil;
}

@end
```

**Response from NSLog on _downloadData

string from _downloadData =

```
{
    "name": "Waipio"
    "address": "100 oak"
    "lat": "28.00"
    "lon": "-125.00"
    "phonenumber": "555"
}
{
    "name": "Murrietta"
    "address": "100 Elm"
    "lat": "83.560852"
    "lon": "-134.135674"
    "phonenumber": "555"
}
```

Comment: In connectionDidFinishLoading, in the for-loop, why are the objectForKey calls done on parsed instead of pointInfo?

Comment: You have to give us some clues. For example, in `connectionDidFinishLoading` do a `NSLog` of `parsed` and edit your question to include that (or at least the first two or three locations), to demonstrate (a) that you successfully downloaded the feed; and (b) that you successfully parsed it. Don't ask us to diagnose code (esp without sharing the JSON file) without showing us some diagnostic information.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should [Use Accessor Methods to Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5). Thus, `self.downloadData = [NSMutableData new];` not `_downloadData = [NSMutableData new];`. Not related to your issue, but you shouldn't generally bypass the accessors methods, [except in the initializer and dealloc methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Comment: Also, you should only use [`start`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW4) "if you create a connection with the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method and provide `NO` for the `startImmediately` parameter."

Comment: @Rob -- I changed the objectForKey calls to pointInfo; that made sense. Still no annotations, though. Sorry for the limited info Rob, I'm trying to ask the right questions and provide the right info, but I'm mostly working from outdated tutorials, I get that I'm missing stuff. I did an NSLog inside the for loop and outside of it, inside the connectionDidFinishLoading method, and got no return each time. I put in a simple string, like "Hello", and that printed but when I tried printing from the array *parsed, I got nothing. So there must not be anything in the array?

Comment: @user2051879 And did you get rid of that `start`, too? You probably want to fix that first. Second, if you're still having problems, you need to just go back step by step and figure out at what point it's going wrong. Did you say that `parsed` was `nil`? How about `_downloadData`? What's in there? Do a `NSLog(@"string from _downloadData = %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_downloadData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` before you parse the JSON and see what it says.

Comment: @Rob Not sure exactly what I need to do to 'fix' the `start`. I updated my question with some sample that was returned from _downloadData. I tried doing the same thing again under parsed, but got no output so I'm not sure if I wrote it correctly.

Comment: @user2061879 you don't "fix" your invocation of the `start` method. You remove it. Your invocation of `connectionWithRequest` starts a connection automatically and you're only starting it a second time by calling `start` manually.

Comment: @Rob Okay, I just removed that. What would I write to properly `NSLOG` the `parsed` dictionary? Also, if I put a breakpoint inside the for loop but the app never stops at the breakpoint - I should assume that it's because there aren't any contents to cycle through in the loop, which would mean something is wrong with the parse from JSON line?

Comment: @Rob Okay, I've got the JSON formatted correctly, [ at the beginning, ] at the end, and a ',' between the end of each object and the next "{},{},{},etc..."

Comment: @user2051879 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24585/discussion-between-rob-and-user2051879)

Comment: @Rob Here's what I got after correcting the JSON:`2013-02-15 10:14:14.037 mapViewTest[29376:c07] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x92afa00
2013-02-15 10:14:14.038 mapViewTest[29376:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x92afa00'`